# Rearranging a triple summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation

I want to rearrange the following triple summation:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\sum_{r=0}^{s}\sum_{q=0}^{r+1} a_{s,r,q}
\end{equation}
in a way that the index in the outermost sum is $r$.

I tried rearranging the sum and have the following answer:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\sum_{s=r}^{\infty}\sum_{q=0}^{r+1} a_{s,r,q}.
\end{equation}

Is this correct?

Comment: I think this might come in handy: $\sum^\infty_{n=0}\sum^\infty_{m=0}a_{m,n}=\sum^\infty_{r=0}\sum^r_{m=0}a_{r-m,m}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, this is  correct, since we can write
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{s=0}^\infty&\sum_{r=0}^s\sum_{q=0}^{r+1}a_{s,r,q}
> =\sum_{\color{blue}{0\leq r\leq s\leq \infty}}\sum_{q=0}^{r+1}a_{s,r,q}
> =\sum_{r=0}^\infty\sum_{s=r}^\infty\sum_{q=0}^{r+1}a_{s,r,q}
> \end{align*}